# Change the webapp name in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

My web app name is tom..I mean url says..`http://localhost:8080/tom/index.do`

i need to change my url to `http://localhost:8080/dave/index.do`..

where exactly I need to make the changes to achieve this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can usually be be done by simply renaming the ".war" file under Tomcat's `webapps` directory (e.g. from "tom.war" to "dave.war"). If you don't see a war file but an exploded directory, you can also rename that directory.

This should work in most basic setups where no context configuration file is used.

Comment: okay..i dont have a war file..i am using spring-context config..i have web.xml, spring--context.xml, hbm.xml files..

Comment: How do you deploy your webapp ?

Comment: using tomcat and ant script to build

Comment: And what is the result of your build if not a war file ? Just a directory with a bunch of files ?

Comment: yes.it is a directory with files..and thanks for mentioning context configurations...it worked..cleaned the cache and ran..its working with new name..thanks!